# Displaying Data in a SQL view, need to save to a SQL table Code First Entity Framework 4.1

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework-4.1

I am supplying data to my MVC 3 website from a SQL view. I'm using the view because I'm having to display data from a different database. How do I go about taking changes that the user makes to the view and save it to the core table?

Comment: I've seen this viewed a couple of times with no answer so I'll see if I can explain this better. I created a view to display data on an MVC 3 page because of where I have to pull the information. the user can only edit 2 fields. I've made a stored procedure which will take the values and save them, but I can't figure out how to trigger the stored procedure and pass in the necessary values. If I take Entity framework out of the picture the proc works fine.